# How to generate a dict from string separated by semicolon?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using Beautifulsoup to search for a specific number in HTML but got stuck here.

```
The raw data is:

<div class='box_content' hn_bookmark='true' ng_init=" bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='000000'; bookmarkable_type=''; ">
```

and I want to extract the "bookmarkable_id".

```
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(text,"html.parser")
questionID_line = bsobj.find("div",{"class":"box_content"})['ng_init']
```

It returns to me a string with words separated by semicolons:

```
bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='793447'; bookmarkable_type='Question'
```

But I don't know how I can extract from here. Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = "bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='793447'; bookmarkable_type='Question'"

fields = {}
for f in data.split('; '):
    k , v = f.split('=')
    fields[k] = v.strip("'")

print(fields)
```

Gives:

```
{'bookmarked': 'false', 'bookmark_id': '', 'bookmarks_path': '/en-US/bookmarks', 'bookmarkable_type': 'Question', 'bookmarkable_id': '793447'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use re to search on questionID_line,

```
import re
re.findall("bookmarkable_id='(.*?)'", questionID_line)
```

Comment: Thx! Actually I was about to find some solution within Beautifulsoup.
But anyway it does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()`:

```
data="bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='793447'; bookmarkable_type='Question'"
output = {i.split("=")[0].strip():i.split("=")[1].strip() for i in data.split(";")}
```

Output

```
{'bookmarks_path': "'/en-US/bookmarks'", 'bookmark_id': "''", 'bookmarked': 'false', 'bookmarkable_id': "'793447'", 'bookmarkable_type': "'Question'"}
```

Feel free to modify `strip()` according to your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
s = """
<div class='box_content' hn_bookmark='true' ng_init=" bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='000000'; bookmarkable_type=''; ">
"""

import re
data = re.findall("bookmark[^=]*='[^']*",s)

dict1 = {}
for j in (data):
    one,two = j.split("=")
    dict1[one] = two.strip("'")

print dict1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't remove the last `"; "` trying to unpack will cause an error as split will leave an odd empty string at the end:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<div class='box_content' hn_bookmark='true' ng_init=" bookmarked=false; bookmark_id=''; bookmarks_path='/en-US/bookmarks'; bookmarkable_id='000000'; bookmarkable_type=''; ">"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

s = soup.select_one("div.box_content")['ng_init']

d = dict(sub.split("=", 1) for sub in s.strip("; ").split("; "))
```